# Cant acces to MAMP after creating Database with Doctrine and Symfony2

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I'm trying to get on with the Symblog Tutorial for Symfony2 (http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/doctrine-2-the-blog-model.html)

After I created my databse with `php app/console doctrine:database:create` I dont have acces to localhost/MAMP/ anymore?! This is the Error Message "Error: Could not connect to MySQL server!"

Can anyone help me?

**Thats my config.yml**

Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:

```
dbal:
    driver:   %database_driver%
    host:     %database_host%
    port:     %database_port%
    dbname:   %database_name%
    user:     %database_user%
    password: %database_password%
    charset:  UTF8
    unix_socket: /var/mysql/mysql.sock

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    auto_mapping: true
```

**Thats my parameters.ini**

```
[parameters]
    database_driver="pdo_mysql"
    database_host="localhost"
    database_port="3306"
    database_name="symfony"
    database_user="root"
    database_password=""
```

Comment: Could you post your `config.yml` and `parameters.ini` files. Just make sure the password you use is masked.

Comment: I posted it to my description..

Comment: Could you check that the "symfony" schema is actually created in your database?

Answer (score 0):

The default port for MAMP server should be 8889 while you are using 3306, the error could be that.

**My parameters**

```
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: '8889'
database_name: symfony_blog
database_user: root
database_password: root
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
locale: en
secret: 7f03537e81f981683bc773b9ec7113ab5861adec
database_path: null
```